# All .kts files become unresolved after upgrading to gradle 7.42, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I upgrade gradle version from 7.33 to 7.41 or higher. Every line in every gradle.kts become unresolved. I tried to replace all lines(except namespace) in corresponding files of a new project created from Android Studio template and there is no problem. I can't figure out what's wrong in my existing project.

project `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    //id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.6.21-1.0.5"
}

val composeVersion: String = rootProject.extra["composeVersion"] as String
val coroutinesVersion: String = rootProject.extra["coroutinesVersion"] as String

android {
    compileSdk = 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.app.myapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix = "-debug"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
    }
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=org.mylibrary.OptInAnnotation"
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = composeVersion
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    namespace = "com.app.myapp"

    applicationVariants.all {
        kotlin.sourceSets {
            getByName(name) {
                kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/ksp/$name/kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")

    // Jetpack Compose
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$composeVersion")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$composeVersion")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1")
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.24.9-beta")
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.24.9-beta")

    // Material design 3
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha12")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.0-alpha12")

    // Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.2")
    implementation("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:animations-core:1.5.7-beta")
    ksp("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:ksp:1.5.7-beta")

    // Hilt
    /*implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42")*/

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion")

    // Nordic ble library
    implementation("no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.6.0")
    implementation("no.nordicsemi.android:ble-ktx:2.4.1")
    implementation("no.nordicsemi.android:ble-common:2.4.1")

    // Java 8+ API desugaring
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$composeVersion")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

app `build.gradle.kts`

```
buildscript {

    val composeVersion by extra("1.2.0-beta02")
    val coroutinesVersion by extra("1.6.1")

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42")
    }

}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false
    id ("com.android.library") version "7.2.0" apply false
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.6.21" apply false
}

tasks.register("clean",Delete::class){
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

`settings.gradle.kts`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My App"
include(":app")
```

Comment: Tried invalidating caches of AS?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.